# Get jQuery $.ajax to send data in body for GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a small function with jQuery Core 2.1.4:

```
function ajax(url, method, data, success) {
  $.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: "json",
    method: method,
    processData: false,
    url: url
  });
}
```

And then this code:

```
var myPage = "http://localhost/blankResponse";
var myFunc = function(data) {
  alert(data);
};

ajax(myPage, "POST", {}, myFunc);   // Request to "testpage" with body
ajax(myPage, "PUT", {}, myFunc);    // Request to "testpage" with body
ajax(myPage, "DELETE", {}, myFunc); // Request to "testpage" with body
ajax(myPage, "GET", {}, myFunc);    // Request to "testpage?{}" with no body
```

GETing adds the `data` parameter to the URL, whereas the other functions add it as the request body. Is there a way I can get (no pun intended!) jQuery to send the data in the request body?

#### Chrome Dev Tools for GET:

[image: GET]

#### Chrome Dev Tools for POST (same for PUT/DELETE):

[image: POST]

Comment: it's regular to add the data to the url when you use `GET` method, are you aware of the differences between `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body. I like the guy's conclusion too: "So, yes, you can send a body with GET, and no, it is never useful to do so."

Comment: @JohnnyFun I don't see how that question is even "relevant," much less a duplicate. I asked how to do X, and you're trying to close it as a duplicate of something that advises against X?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Look up the definition of GET. Link is totally relevant

Comment: Thank you, gentlemen. Dude, we're just trying to point you in the right direction. HTTP is a protocol. We programmers avoid violating protocols unless it's absolutely necessary so we can read each other's crap easier. Perhaps the solution is to modify your "ajax" function to use jquery's $.param function if the method is a get and append the result to the url and skip passing it as the request body. Kna mean?

Comment: @JohnnyFun the issue is that a URI ignores any notion of character encoding, MIME type, etc. I don't doubt that it's not standard to send GET data in a request body, but it makes no sense that request data is in the body for POST, etc., but in the URI for GET. It adds additional complexity to internals ("if GET then get from URI, else get from body").